# C++ file->SendRequest returning ANSI instead of UTF8

Tags: c++, mfc

I hope you are fine..

Please, I am doing a C++ request: file->SendRequest
(class CHttpFile afxinet.h )

When I retrieve this data(get request) it seems it is encoded as ANSI and the source file from this request is econdeded as UTF8.
I am reading it using file->ReadString .

```
void request(){

  connection1 = session.GetHttpConnection(host, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, Port, NULL, NULL); 
  file1 = connection1->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_GET, var2, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, inetFlags);
file1->SendRequest();
aux1 = file->ReadString(sz1, 10000);}
```

The aux1 variable is receiving this value as ANSI encoding
and the special characters for spanish language are missed.

How should I do in order to retrieve this data as UTF8?
It is Microsoft MFC.
Regards,

William

Comment: Since it's not standard C++, add tags for what framework you are using to do the request. I _think_ it's a Microsoft MFC class, but I can't be sure. Try making a [mcve] too.

Comment: You should provide more context around the code you're asking about. Also, try to format it with the corresponding formatting block as it will be easier to read it.

Comment: There's a 95% chance you've misdiagnosed the location of the encoding issue. We really need a [mcve].

Comment: Call [Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cinternetfile-class#read) in place of `ReadString` to get the raw bytes. When done you can perform any character encoding conversions you need (e.g. from UTF-8 to UTF-16).

Comment: Hi All,

I have just converted the result of file->ReadString into UTF-8.

It worked fine.

Many thanks all for you help.